# Undefined index: simple_sku Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, error, log

I am writing code in magento 1.9 checkout and when adding a new product to cart it generates the error in the log, and my code seems to be correct.

Error message that appears in the log.
[image]

The problem is that I don't understand the reason for the error if the code seems to be correct.
I'm trying to get a code a value from the following array.

[image]

My code is the following:

[image]

Why can't I call this value using "$_customOptions['simple_sku']" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a configurable to the cart both the configurable and simple child products will be in the cart, only 1 is visible and represented in the cart on the frontend. So depending on how you loaded the `$cart` varible then that will probably contain multiple products.
To skip the product that doesn't have the option change your code to,

`if(isset($_customOptions['simple_sku']) && is_string($_customOptions['simple_sku'])){`

Then this will ensure it's not accessed with the array key is not set.